# Pandas correlation maxtrix between float columns and string columns

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

How can I get a correlation matrix in Pandas between float columns and string columns? Using `df.corr()` automatically drops the string columns. I tried `pd.get_dummies()`, but this "widens" the dataframe and returns 1/0 in the widened columns.

The purpose is to plot a heatmap of the correlation. Of course 'dog' and 'dog' will have a correlation of unity, but I want to see the correlation of 'dog' and x, 'pig' and x, etc.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [3,2,5,1,1,0,7],
     'category': ['dog','dog','cat','pig','dog','cat','pig']}
)
```

```
    x   category
0   3   dog
1   2   dog
2   5   cat
3   1   pig
4   1   dog
5   0   cat
6   7   pig
```

Comment: It really doesn't make sense. If you have ordinal categories where you can say that one is < the other (imagine high medium, low) then fine. However if you have something like 'cat', 'dog', 'pig' your choice of whether cat=1, dog=2, pig=3 or cat=2, dog=1, pig=3 will lead to entirely different correlations. The correlation of X with columns of dummies makes more sense in those cases.

Comment: @ALollz that is a good point, thank you, updated OP considering your points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `pd.get_dummies()`, but this "widens" the dataframe and returns 1/0 in the widened columns.

If I understand correctly, that's exactly what you need here. It ["one-hot encodes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot#Machine_learning_and_statistics) the nominal variables so that we don't artificially introduce ordinal relationships.

```py
df = pd.get_dummies(df)

#    x  cat  dog  pig
# 0  3    0    1    0
# 1  2    0    1    0
# 2  5    1    0    0
# 3  1    0    0    1
# 4  1    0    1    0
# 5  0    1    0    0
# 6  7    0    0    1
```

Then you can use `corr()` (as for how much it makes sense, that's another story):

```py
df.corr()

#             x       cat       dog       pig
# x    1.000000 -0.058610 -0.267516  0.351659
# cat -0.058610  1.000000 -0.547723 -0.400000
# dog -0.267516 -0.547723  1.000000 -0.547723
# pig  0.351659 -0.400000 -0.547723  1.000000
```

[image: one-hot corr heatmap]